# Make a DataRow class that implements ILiquidizable

Tags: .net, asp.net, liquid

I'm trying to use [Dot Liquid](https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid/) which is one of the coolest templating engines for c#.
Dot Liquid uses a way in order to make using templates safe. [Here is the explanation page.](https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid/wiki/DotLiquid-Drops)

**Here is the Explanation from it's wiki:**

> DotLiquid, by default, only accepts a
>   limited number of types as parameters
>   to the Render method - including the
>   .NET primitive types(int, float,
>   string, etc.), and some collection
>   types including IDictionary, IList and
>   IIndexable (a custom DotLiquid
>   interface).
>
> If it supported arbitrary types, then
>   it could result in properties or
>   methods being unintentionally exposed
>   to template authors. To prevent this,
>   DotLiquid uses Drop objects. Drops use
>   an opt-in approach to exposing object
>   data.
>
> The Drop class is just one
>   implementation of ILiquidizable, and
>   the simplest way to expose your
>   objects to DotLiquid templates is to
>   implement ILiquidizable directly

**Wiki Sample Code:**

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class UserDrop : Drop
{
    private readonly User _user;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _user.Name; }
    }

    public UserDrop(User user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }
}

Template template = Template.Parse("Name: {{ user.name }}; Email: {{ user.email }};");
string result = template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new
{
    user = new UserDrop(new User
    {
        Name = "Tim",
        Email = "me@mydomain.com"
    })
}));
```

So when I pass DataRow to liquid, liquid wont let me show it's content and tells me that:

> 'System.Data.DataRow' is invalid
>   because it is neither a built-in type
>   nor implements ILiquidizable

Is there any solutions to pass DataRow object that implements ILiquidizable too? 
Thanks

Comment: You will probably have to convert the `DataRow` to a class instance of your own, which implements `ILiquidizable`. I don't see how you could make an existing class like `DataRow` suddenly support a new interface....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As marc_s indicated, you'll need to convert the `DataRow` object to your own class instance, or at least wrap it with your own class instance. I'd suggest wrapping it like this:

```
internal class DataRowDrop : Drop
{
    private readonly DataRow _dataRow;

    public DataRowDrop(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        _dataRow = dataRow;    
    }

    public override object BeforeMethod(string method)
    {
        if (_dataRow.Table.Columns.Contains(method))
            return _dataRow[method];
        return null;
    }
}
```

Sample usage would be:

```
[Test]
public void TestDataRowDrop()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Column1");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Column2");

    DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
    dataRow["Column1"] = "Hello";
    dataRow["Column2"] = "World";

    Template tpl = Template.Parse(" {{ row.column1 }} ");
    Assert.AreEqual(" Hello ", tpl.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new
    {
        row = new DataRowDrop(dataRow)
    })));
}
```

I've also added this example drop class, and the corresponding unit test, to the [unit tests for DotLiquid drops](https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid/blob/master/src/DotLiquid.Tests/DropTests.cs).

Comment: in some cases might need to check DbNull: `code` if (_dataRow.Table.Columns.Contains(method) && !_dataRow.IsNull(method))
                    obj = _dataRow[method];`code`